# sssd No domains configured, fatal error

Tags: sssd

sssd runnig one client but fails another,
any idea?

system is Centos 7 x64, running on proxmox VM

```
# journalctl -xe
-- Unit sssd.service has begun starting up.
Ağu 20 09:20:17 slreport.linktera.lan sssd[31252]: Starting up
Ağu 20 09:20:17 slreport.linktera.lan systemd[1]: sssd.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=4/NOPERMISSION
Ağu 20 09:20:17 slreport.linktera.lan systemd[1]: Failed to start System Security Services Daemon.
```

```
# cat /var/log/sssd/sssd.log
(Tue Aug 20 09:20:17 2019) [sssd] [confdb_get_domains] (0x0010): No domains configured, fatal error!
(Tue Aug 20 09:20:17 2019) [sssd] [main] (0x0010): No domains configured.
```

my sssd.conf is

```
[sssd]
debug_level = 9
domains = linktera.lan
services = nss, sudo, pam, ssh, ifp

[domain/LINKTERA.LAN]
cache_credentials = True
krb5_store_password_if_offline = True
ipa_domain = linktera.lan
id_provider = ipa
auth_provider = ipa
access_provider = ipa
ipa_hostname = slreport.linktera.lan
chpass_provider = ipa
ipa_server = _srv_, ipa.linktera.lan
ldap_tls_cacert = /etc/ipa/ca.crt

[nss]
homedir_substring = /home

[pam]

[sudo]

[autofs]

[ssh]

[pac]

[ifp]

[secrets]

[session_recording]
```

what is the problem?

Answer (score 1):

> [sssd] [confdb_get_domains] (0): No domains configured, fatal error!

SSSD requires that the configuration file be properly set up, with all the required entries, before the daemon will start. The SSSD service will only start when there is at least one properly configured domain setup.

Edit `/etc/sssd/sssd.conf` file and create at least one domain.

Answer (score 0):

I solved,

i changed system config language Turkish to English,
problem suddenly disappeared.

now sssd is working.

```
yum install system-config-language
system-config-language --text
```